# How to use an External Stylesheet in Polymer 2.0

Tags: css, polymer-2.x

I am new to this so please go easy...

I am trying to style a Polymer 2.0 custom element using an external stylesheet, however I cannot get the external stylesheet to apply to the element.

This is the element I am trying to style (web-app.html):

```
<link rel="import" href="../elements/Styles/style-web-app.html">

<dom-module id="web-app">
<template>
<div id="header-container" class="header-container">
<div id="logo">
<img id="Mono" class="logo" src="../img/mono_primary_white_RGB.png" 
height="75px" width="75px" />
</div>
<div id="header">
<h1 id="title">ICR</h1>
</div>
</div>
<div id="tabs">
<paper-tabs selected="{{selected}}">
<paper-tab name="Name">Name</paper-tab>
<paper-tab name="Type">Type</paper-tab>
<paper-tab name="Usages">Usages</paper-tab>
</paper-tabs>
</div>
</template>
```

And this is the External Stylesheet code (style-web-app.html):

```
<dom-module id="style-web-app">
<template>
<style>
:host{
#title {
font-size: 30px;
/* text-align: center; */
width: 500px;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
#header-container, #tabs {
background-color: #01579B;
display: flex;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
#header {
display: inline-block;
}
}
</style>
</template>
</dom-module>
```

Could someone please tell me where I am going wrong?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pseudo example taken straight out of the Polymer 2.0 documentation.

 Once you've created a stylesheet to share, you can import it in the element you want to add that style to and apply them using **include** in the `<style>` -

```
<!-- Create Your external Style document -->
<dom-module id="my-style-module">
  <template>
    <style>
      p {
       color: red;
      }
      <!-- rest of styles to share go here! -->
    </style>
  </template>
</dom-module>


<!-- import custom-style -->
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/lib/elements/custom-style.html">
<link rel="import" href="my-style-module.html">
<dom-module>
 <template>
   <style include="my-style-module">
     <!-- custom element style go here! -->
   </style>

  <p>Paragraph A: I am in the main DOM. I am red.</p>
 </template>

 <script>
  //Your custom element script
 </script>
</dom-module>
```

so, in your example, you'll have to update the `web-app.html` to include styling from `style-web-app` as -

```
<style include="style-web-app">
         <!-- custom element style go here! -->
</style>
```

You can read up further on custom styling and external stylesheets [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/style-shadow-dom#external-stylesheets)